# Is there any Javascript engine that emits LLVM bytecode?

Tags: javascript, llvm

I've been searching for a while now, but I could not find any engine that emits LLVM bytecode.
But somehow I cannot belief there is no such engine :)

Comment: IIRC mozilla investigated the possibility of using LLVM as a backend for their JIT but ruled it out, saying it would be too slow or something like that

Comment: @CAFxX: Do you have any reference about that?

Comment: @Albert sure: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/tracemonkey-overview/comment-page-2/#comment-67629

Comment: [LLV8](https://github.com/ispras/llv8) is an experimental top-tier compiler for V8 JavaScript Engine. LLV8 leverages the power of LLVM MCJIT to produce highly optimized code.
last commit was on Sep 8, 2016.

Answer (score 9):

JXcore will be your best bet going forward IMHO - when they convert from V8 to LLVM, which is an objective of theirs when they reach version 2 (according to their roadmap), it will then compile your javascript sources into native code.

You can get more info on JXcore [here](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore).

This part of the answer is in a response to Albert's answer:

According to ktrzeciaknubisa's [post](https://github.com/Nubisa/jxdocs/issues/17#issuecomment-38666410) they will publish the source as soon as they are out of the beta stages and have clean code...this might take some time.

Comment: Nubisa halted active development on the JXcore platform.

Comment: Looks like it has now been replaced by this project: https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile

Comment: ...although it looks like `nodejs-mobile` is using V8, so I guess we still have to look to earlier projects for examples of targeting LLVM.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any.

In the list of [projects build with LLVM](http://llvm.org/ProjectsWithLLVM/) there is nothing about Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It appears Webkit now includes this functionality as of May 2014:

> ... the WebKit project has unified its existing JavaScript compilation infrastructure with the state-of-the-art LLVM optimizer.

https://webkit.org/blog/3362/introducing-the-webkit-ftl-jit/

The code for this seems to be here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore-7600.1.4.17.5/ftl/FTLLowerDFGToLLVM.cpp

Comment: They've since replaced LLVM with the Bare Bones Backend.  https://webkit.org/blog/5852/introducing-the-b3-jit-compiler/

Answer (score 1):

JXCore (a fork of Nodejs) claims to have implemented that. Since Feb 2015, it is open source, the code is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore).

Comment: Where is it stated, that JXcore is a commercial fork? In the contrary - it is an open source project https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore (starting from mid of Feb 2015, but was never commercial though)

Comment: But they moved that to "somewhere down the road" and use V8 and SpiderMonkey now