# How to convert javascript to LLVM IR?

Tags: javascript, llvm, llvm-ir

Is there any LLVM backend for javascript? If not, other tools that convert dynamic language(similar to javascript) to LLVM IR will also be okay. 
Because I am writing a dynamic language compiler and such tools can help me find out how some features are implemented.

Comment: For which programming language is the compiler being written?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466824/is-there-any-javascript-engine-that-emits-llvm-bytecode

Comment: @AndersonGreen It is just a toy language created by myself, similar to javascript.

Comment: there are few projects on github  about it. One of them is TypeScript Native Compiler (https://github.com/ASDAlexander77/TypeScriptCompiler)

Answer (score 4):

[FTL JIT](https://webkit.org/blog/3362/introducing-the-webkit-ftl-jit/) (JavaScriptCore) uses LLVM as a backend.

Other VMs for dynamic languages using LLVM MCJIT:

- [Pyston](https://github.com/dropbox/pyston)
- [HHVM](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm)
- [LLILC](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc)
- [Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia)
- The list goes on

Comment: As of Feb 2016, FTL JIT (Webkit) no longer uses LLVM; they use B3 (Bare Bones Backend) JIT: https://webkit.org/blog/5852/introducing-the-b3-jit-compiler/