# How to compile WebAssembly into regular assembly / native code (or Cpp, etc)?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, llvm, webassembly

There's plenty of info on compiling *to* WebAssembly from languages like C++ or Rust, F.e. there's plenty of search resuilts on LLVM to Wasm, but what about WASM to LLVM.

But is there a way to compile *from* WebAssembly to regular assembly (or other "native" languages like C++ or ASM)?

Note, this is not a duplicate of [How to convert javascript to LLVM IR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313561/how-to-convert-javascript-to-llvm-ir). This issue is not about converting JavaScript to native code, it is about converting WebAssembly to native code (f.e. native machine code). JavaScript and WebAssembly are different things.

Comment: A possible duplicate from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313561/how-to-convert-javascript-to-llvm-ir ?

Comment: @Amadeus As far as I understand the linked question and its answers correctly, it is only about tools that can convert JavaScript to native code. These tools seem not to be able to convert WebAssembly to native code.

Comment: There are decompilers. Of course you can't create a regular assembly automatically. But possibly with (probably not insignificant) manual effort (I didn't try it myself): https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb/#wasm

Comment: Most browsers turn WebAssembly into regular machine language.

Comment: @Amadeus Maybe it isn't a duplicate, because JavaScript is not the same as WebAssembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few experimental facility exist. The **Liftoff** (google V8 embedded) compiler for WebAssembly must be doing this task internally; I am not aware of any exposed V8 API for application to use it for this task.

**Lucetc** says, it can compiles WebAssembly modules (.wasm or .wat files) into native code (.o or .so files).
https://github.com/fastly/lucet

**wasm2c**: says, it can convert wasm files to C source and header
https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/tree/master/wasm2c

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks for sharing those! Exactly what I asking about. I will expand on this answer if I find more.